# error: java.io.IOException caused by com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Blob hash mismatch

Tags: azure, hash, azure-blob-storage, databricks

I have a csv.gz file on Azure blob store of about the size 1.4GB
I am reading from that Azure blob as shown below into a dataframe and then creating a new dataframe with a join with spark stream data coming from Azure eventhub(in mini batch):

```
val data = spark.read.option("sep", ",").csv(path)
data.count() // -> here the correct count is returned
val res = input.join(data, $"key1" == $"key2")
```

This code runs perfectly well locally, but when I run on Databricks I get the following error at the line of the join(the previous 2 lines to get the daaframe from azure blob and get its count worked!):

```
java.io.IOException
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Utility.initIOException(Utility.java:737)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobInputStream.dispatchRead(BlobInputStream.java:264)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobInputStream.readInternal(BlobInputStream.java:448)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobInputStream.read(BlobInputStream.java:420)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$NativeAzureFsInputStream.read(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:855)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FSInputStreamWithMetrics$$anonfun$read$3.apply$mcI$sp(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:206)
at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FSInputStreamWithMetrics$$anonfun$read$3.apply(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:206)
at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FSInputStreamWithMetrics$$anonfun$read$3.apply(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:206)
at com.databricks.spark.metrics.ExtendedTaskIOMetrics$class.withTimeMetric(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:151)
at com.databricks.spark.metrics.ExtendedTaskIOMetrics$class.com$databricks$spark$metrics$ExtendedTaskIOMetrics$$withTimeAndBytesMetric(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:171)
at com.databricks.spark.metrics.ExtendedTaskIOMetrics$$anonfun$withTimeAndBytesReadMetric$1.apply$mcI$sp(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:185)
at com.databricks.spark.metrics.ExtendedTaskIOMetrics$$anonfun$withTimeAndBytesReadMetric$1.apply(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:185)
at com.databricks.spark.metrics.ExtendedTaskIOMetrics$$anonfun$withTimeAndBytesReadMetric$1.apply(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:185)
at com.databricks.spark.metrics.SamplerWithPeriod.sample(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:78)
at com.databricks.spark.metrics.ExtendedTaskIOMetrics$class.withTimeAndBytesReadMetric(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:185)
at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FSInputStreamWithMetrics.withTimeAndBytesReadMetric(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:192)
at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FSInputStreamWithMetrics.read(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:205)
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.getCompressedData(DecompressorStream.java:159)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:85)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:186)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.hasNext(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:69)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:462)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:228)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:196)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:638)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedRDDBuilder$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedRDDBuilder$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:222)
at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:299)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1170)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1161)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1096)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1161)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:883)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:351)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:302)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:340)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:340)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:340)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeCartesianRDD.compute(CartesianProductExec.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:340)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:340)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:340)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:340)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1481)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Blob hash mismatch (integrity check failed), Expected value is 2KZt/fYpaL8Xd7RHo+RnUg==, retrieved CkctlJmHlHFLA8YGxhhuMg==.
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob$9.postProcessResponse(CloudBlob.java:1409)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob$9.postProcessResponse(CloudBlob.java:1310)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:149)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.downloadRangeInternal(CloudBlob.java:1493)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobInputStream.dispatchRead(BlobInputStream.java:255)
```

Anybody else faced similar issue? Any idea what could be going wrong here? I have exactly followed this link here to upload the blob to azure storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java

Thanks.

Comment: What is the `input` variable in the line `val res = input.join(data, $"key1" == $"key2")`?

Comment: `input` is a spark streaming data as dataframe.

Comment: I think the issue here is that the join is taking place before the entire upload has completed. How to ensure if the upload was complete and successful before proceeding to next step?